# Attaching appenders to classes in config file in Log4net

Tags: c#-4.0, log4net

I managed to get started with Log4net but all my classes are using the same appender.
I want some classes to use a special appender.

Following is my log file:

```xml
<appender name="InfoRollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender,log4net">
  <param name="File" value="C:\Test.log"/>
  <param name="RollingStyle" value="Date"/>
  <param name="DatePattern" value="_yyyy-MM-dd.log"/>
  <param name="StaticLogFileName" value="true"/>
  <maximumFileSize value="100KB" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%newline ---------------START---------------------- %newline %date - %message %newline ----------------END--------------------- %newline" />
  </layout>
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
    <levelMin value="DEBUG" />
    <levelMax value="DEBUG" />
  </filter>
  <filter class="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter"/>
</appender>

<root>
  <level value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="InfoRollingLogFileAppender" />
</root>
```

Here is how I am using it in my  code:

```
private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

and then to log I use `log.Debug("Goes in Log File")`.

My question is how can I have different appenders for specific classes?

Answer (score 3):

You can define appenders per logger which in your case translates to "per class":

```xml
<root>
   <level value="DEBUG" />
   <appender-ref ref="InfoRollingLogFileAppender" />
</root>
<logger name="YourNameSpace.YourClass" additivity="false">
   <level value="DEBUG" />
   <appender-ref ref="YourOtherAppender" />
</logger>
```

Important is the `additivity` flag: Without it the appenders defined in the root (or parent) logger are inherited.